# Adding Stack Exchange account as a login

Tags: support, login, accounts

I already have Stack Overflow login but I want to add Stack Exchange account. When I go to add logins page I can't see Stack Exchange option. How can I add it?

[image]

Comment: The 'stackoverflow' login *is* the Stack Exchange OpenID server. On your 'My Logins' dialog box, you'll already have a 'Stack Exchange' entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that text input field, enter https://openid.stackexchange.com and log in using your Stack Exchange info. :)

I just had this same issue because I have Google and MyOpenID as login accounts and I want to get rid of them.